# Where can I check Ionic's compiler error output?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic and this is the message:

> BUILD FAILED C:\adt\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following error
>   occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\adt\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler
>   error output for details.
>
> Total time: 5 seconds
>
> C:\wamp\www\external\projectx\dirx\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126

Where can I see the log details? I've tried googling a bunch of things like "ionic log path" etc but nothing comes up. I saw something else that said run it with a -c argument but the output is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you update your sdk, sometimes error occur when trying to build android incompatible API to your cordova version or ionic.